# ios 6 navigation bar and status bar overlapped

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

The problem is like this:
My status bar is intially hidden.
I have a tab bar controller and it has a navigation controller in each of its tabs.
Screen shot is like:
[image]

Later I clicked on a button on the navigation controller's view, I would like to reveal the status bar, but it ends like this:[image]

the navigation bar overlaps the status bar. I have to perform some actions like tapping another tab to make the navigation bar go down.

I tried to set status bar to UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque and it worked fine.
But if I press the "home" button on iphone to turn the app to bacground and the switch back to active, the problem occurs again if I clicked on the button. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your status bar style is `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`. You should set it to either `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` or `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` for the desired effect.

Translucent status bars overlap the full screen views, while opaque ones push those views down.

Answer (score 0):

click on button, do following things:

```
 self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque]; //or UIStatusBarStyleDefault
```